# Calculate Average engagement time in GA4 (Google Analytics 4) using measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I am creating chrome extension and trying to pass the data to GA4(Google Analytics 4) using measurement protocol.How I can send session start and session end time  to GA4 using measurement protocol so that it can be use to display Average engagement time, Engaged sessions per user, Average engagement time per session in the Enagement > Overview section.

1.In the params section I tried to pass the session_start : "1" parameter using measurement protocol.

```
    {
       "client_id": "x",
       "events": [{
        "name": "offline_purchase",
        "params": {
          "engagement_time_msec": "100",
          "session_id": "123",
          "session_start" : "1"
        }
      ]}
    }
```

2.Also tried to send the session_start parameter through url

```
const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
        const api_secret = `<secret_value>`;
        fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?
        measurement_id=${measurement_id}&
        api_secret=${api_secret}&session_start=${1}`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
            events: [{
              name: 'tutorial_begin',
              params: {},
            }]
          })
        });
```

Comment: you don't it calculates it based on session start and end

Comment: How to pass those parameters using measurement protocol?